Would like some help in understanding the useState generic definition please
In a course I'm doing on TS, they introduce this definition for useState generics but it was skimmed over and I'd like to understand better
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): 
[S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];

from my understanding after reading many things about this, I follow most of it but am lost by the Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>> part, I see that the type is passed into SetStateAction but not sure how its working and what goes to Dispatch, would like a good explanation of this please.

It's a type, nothing "goes to Dispatch". The return value of useState is an array in which the first element is the same type as what you marked useState as returning (obviously) and the second is a React-specific thing of type Dispatch that dispatches a React-specific type called SetStateAction that has generics to match the typing of the thing you're using useState for. It's one  of those "this is just how React works, you will never manually create your own useState, and you don't have to understand how React internally types stuff" situations.

Dispatch is a type which the react library has defined. That type's definition is:
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;

Ie, a function that takes in some value, and returns nothing. Consequently this:
Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>

... is the same as:
(value: SetStateAction<S>) => void;

That prompts us to find out what SetStateAction is, and it's this:
type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);

Ie, it's either a value, or a function that receives the previous value and returns a new one
So putting it all together, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>> is the same as:
(value: S | ((prevState: S) => S)) => void;

In other words, it's a function that you can either pass a new value into, or you can pass an update function into it.
eg:
const [name, setName] = useState<string>('alice'); // <string> is optional, because typescript can figure it out from context

// Can either pass in a string
setName('bob');
// or a function that both receives and returns a string.
setName((prev: string) => {
  return prev + ', the almighty';
});


That really helped how you broke it down as I'm new to this, thanks. Where did you find the type definitions? is there an easy way to locate them?

Not sure what editor you're using, but in VS Code you can right click on Dispatch (or any type) and select "go to definition" to jump to that spot in the source code. ctrl-clicking on Dispatch has the same effect.

You can also find all of the declarations in GitHub https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L1823
